# regular expression or function to correctly display an apartment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

The input function should accept a string which can start with numbers, letters (both English and Russian) and can also include special characters such as - and /. The field should also allow for the input to be left empty. Example: /^[\p{L}0-9-/]*$/u. Therefore, the strings 23, 23A, 23b, 23д, 5/С, 100-Б should all be valid inputs.

How can I do this? I tried several RegEx combinations but they didn't help.

```
const BorrowerForm = (props) => {
  //aprtment
  const [addrFlat, setAddrFlat] = useState('');
  //helper
  const [HelperMessage, setHelperMessage] = useState('');
  const [notMessageError, setNotMessageError] = useState('');

  const ref_flat = useRef(null);

  const clearErrors = () => {
    //for apartment helper
    setHelperMessage('');
    setNotMessageError(false);
  };


  const validate = () => {
    let notCorrectText = 'Please fill in the correct field';
    let hasErrors = false;

    if (addrFlat.length > 6) {
      setHelperMessage(notCorrectText);
      setNotMessageError(true);
      hasErrors = true;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <TextField
          ref={ref_flat}
          className="input addr_flat"
          label="appartment"
          variant="outlined"
          value={addrFlat}
          error={notMessageError}
          helperText={HelperMessage}
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={(event) => change(setAddrFlat, event)}
        />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BorrowerForm;
```

Comment: _"I tried several RegEx combinations"_ - please _show us_ what you actually tried, instead of just _telling_ us that you tried something.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, sorry for not showing
  const REGEX =  ('^[A-Za-zA-Яа-я-z0-9\s\-\/]*$')

Comment: `A-Z` and `A-Я`, with what appears to be the exact same `A` character, makes no sense to begin with. Assuming the second interval was valid to begin with (I didn't check, what positions `A` and `Я` actually have), you would at most get one interval that completely contains the other one here.